# Where to find C++ reference for Internet Explorer extension

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I've just started building an extension for internet explorer using c++. I haven't been able to find the reference for it, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browser Extensions reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753587%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Found this reference, seems pretty reasonable

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317(v=VS.85).aspx